# Callback function not working in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Creating an example to learn callbacks in `Flutter`. It's a simple programme to increase the counter onTap of a `GestureDetetor` But, the callback method is not working. The count increase on hot reload but not on tap. Below is the code with comments.

```
class BoxState extends State<ChangeBoxState>{
  int _counter = 0;

  //Callback method changes the state onTap of GestureDetector widget. It is not calling onTap.
  increaseCount(){
    setState(() {
      ++_counter;
      print(_counter);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Passing the callback method,"increaseCount()" to stateless class where GestureDetector is defined.
    return BoxWidget(onPressed: increaseCount(), counter: _counter,);
  }

}
```

Stateless class:

```
class BoxWidget extends StatelessWidget{

  BoxWidget({this.onPressed, this.counter});

  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final int counter;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[500]),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[Center(child: Text('Hello, world!')),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: onPressed, //Passing onPressed to onTap.

          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left:0.0, top:200.0, right:0.0, bottom:0.0),
            height: 200.0,
            width: 200.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.teal[200],
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow, width: 10.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
            ),
            child: Center(child: Text(counter.toString())),
          ),
        ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove the the bracket in `increaseCount()` because using the bracket  you are creating an instance of your `VoidCallback`  and this will run one time  only so try this

```
return BoxWidget(onPressed: increaseCount, counter: _counter,);
```

Comment: Tahnks @Raouf, It would good if  you could elaborate the difference a little. Please!

Comment: @PorasBhardwaj what do you want exactly to know ?

Comment: @RaoufRahiche I wanted to know what happened when we pass increaseCount() or increaseCount. Natwar elobrate a little in his answer. Please share If you have more info.

Comment: Hi @RaoufRahiche, I just had exactly same issue. I don't really understand, why it works without (). Could you please explain more in depth about it?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the reference of `increaseCount` to the `onPressed` callback.

Here you are assigning `increaseCount()` (check braces) to the callback which first call `increaseCount()` function and its return value will be assigned to the `onPressed`. Thats why it is only incrementing one time on hot reload.

```
return BoxWidget(onPressed: increaseCount, counter: _counter,);
```